# I want to proportionally resize an image according to the viewport

Tags: jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a Wordpress theme with Twitter Bootsrap and I am using the Jumbotron as an image slider on the homepage.

I want it to resize the images according to the viewport and to achieve this I am using the following code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.carousel .item').css({
        'min-height':(jQuery(window).height())/100*85+'px'
    });
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        $('.carousel .item').css({
            'min-height':(jQuery(window).height())/100*85+'px'
        });
    });
});

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.carousel img').css({
        'min-height':(jQuery(window).height())/100*85+'px'
    });
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        $('.carousel img').css({
            'min-height':(jQuery(window).height())/100*85+'px'
        });
    });
});
```

This works great to adjust the image's height but may also cause it to lose proportion.

Any ideas how I can remedy this?

Comment: Why not just set the 'width' of the img, the height will be adjust automatically and keep its proportion?

Comment: have a look at max-width 100% in your css